# Question about a topology of complements of compacts

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Suppose that $(X,T)$ is a non-compact Hausdroff space and $T'=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{X-K: K$ is $T$-compact$\}$.

Would $X$ equipped with $T'$ have to be a second countable space? Or at least first countable? How about separability? Also, is it  locally compact?

My thoughts on this:

I found that $(X,T')$ is compact and that every closed subset of it is also compact. It's non-Hausdorff and weaker than $T$.

I did the most natural thing taking $X = \Bbb R$ as a start. I found this to be locally compact, I'm not sure though of its other properties. It's claimed somewhere on the Internet that it is in fact second countable.

So the example of $\Bbb R$ is not much insightful. I am having hard time thinking of a suitable example that would disprove local compactness, let alone the other properties.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take an uncountable set with the discrete topology $T$.  Then you can show $T'$ is not second countable...

Answer (score 3):

Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be an uncountable discrete space. Then the only $\tau$-compact subsets of $X$ are the finite sets, and $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is certainly locally compact, non-compact, and Hausdorff. But $\tau'$ is just the cofinite topology, which certainly isn’t second countable.

**Added:** The construction of $\tau'$ from a locally compact, non-compact, Hausdorff topology $\tau$ on some set $X$ will always result in a compact space. Suppose that $\mathscr{U}$ is a $\tau'$-open cover of $X$. Let $\mathscr{F}=\{X\setminus U:U\in\mathscr{U}\}$; then $\mathscr{F}$ is a family of $\tau$-compact sets with empty intersection, so there must be a finite $\mathscr{U}_0\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ such that $\bigcap_{U\in\mathscr{U}_0}(X\setminus U)=\varnothing$ and therefore $\bigcup\mathscr{U}_0=X$.

**Added<sub>2</sub>:** Let $\tau$ be the usual order topology on $X=\omega_1$; $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is locally compact, non-compact, and Hausdorff, and its compact sets are precisely those that are closed and bounded in the usual order. Thus, the non-empty members of $\tau'$ are the $U\in\tau$ for which there is an $\eta<\omega_1$ such that $\{\xi\in X:\eta<\xi\}\subseteq U$. If $D\subseteq X$ is countable, then $\{\xi\in X>\sup D<\xi\}$ is a $\tau'$-open set disjoint from $D$, so $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ is not separable.

**Added<sub>3</sub>:** For completeness I’m adding the result (from the comments below) that $\tau'$ is always a locally compact topology if $\tau$ is. We first show that if $C\subseteq X$ is $\tau$-closed, then $C$ is $\tau'$-compact. Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a $\tau'$-open cover of $C$, and for each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ let $K_U=X\setminus U$; $K_U$ is $\tau$-compact. Fix $V\in\mathscr{U}$; then $C\cap K_V$ is $\tau$-closed and hence $\tau$-compact. Since $\tau'\subseteq\tau$, $\mathscr{U}\setminus\{V\}$ is a $\tau$-open cover of $C\cap K_V$, so there is a finite $\mathscr{U}_0\subseteq\mathscr{U}\setminus\{V\}$ such that $C\cap K_V\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}_0$. But then $\mathscr{U}_0\cup\{V\}$ is a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ that covers $C$, which is therefore $\tau'$-compact.

Now let $x\in X$, and let $U$ be a $\tau'$-open nbhd of $x$. Let $K=X\setminus U$. Each $y\in K$ has a $\tau$-open nbhd whose $\tau$-closure is $\tau$-compact and does not contain $x$, and $K$ is $\tau$-compact, so $K$ has a $\tau$-open nbhd $V$ whose $\tau$-closure is $\tau$-compact and does not contain $x$. Let $W=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}_\tau V$; then $W$ is a $\tau'$-open nbhd of $x$, and $\operatorname{cl}_\tau W\subseteq X\setminus V\subseteq X\setminus K=U$, so $\operatorname{cl}_\tau W$ is a $\tau'$-compact $\tau'$-nbhd of $x$ contained in $U$, and $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ is locally compact.

Comment: I see. This is also not first countable. But it's separable. And I'm not sure about local compactness. Can you give an example where the latter two fail? I thought maybe if $T$ is chosen so that $T'$ is the cocountable topology, I get a non-locally-compact space. For separability, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Cauchy: You’ll always get a compact space; I just added a proof. I’ll have to think about separability.

Comment: But according to the definition I'm using, compactness doesn't give local compactness. The one I'm using is: at each point there is a local base consisting of compact sets

Comment: @Cauchy: Okay. You still local compactness in the case of the cofinite topology, since it’s even hereditarily compact.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being bothersome, but I want to know whether or not $T'$ is **necessarily locally compact**. So an example in which local compactness is achieved isn't useful

Comment: I figured out: it has to be locally compact because every $T$-closed is $T'$-compact: if $A \subset X$ is $T$-closed and $A \subset \cup_{a \in I} (X\setminus K_a)$ where the $K_a$ are $T$-compact, then choose any $b \in I$. We have $A\cap K_b$ is $T$-closed in $K_b$, so it is $T$-compact, therefore as $A\cap K_b \subset \cup_{a\in I} (X\setminus K_a)$, there exists a finite $J\subset I$ such that $A\cap K_b \subset \cup_{a\in J} (X\setminus K_a)$, therefore $A \subset \cup_{a \in J'}(X \setminus K_a)$ where $J'=J \cup \{b\}$..

Comment: ..therefore $A$ is $T'$-compact. So given $x$ we can take the set of $T$-closures of $T'$-neighborhoods of $x$ and we get a compact local base.

Comment: @Cauchy: I understood that that’s what you were asking; I simply had nothing useful to say about it at that point. \\ Your argument is fine as far as it goes, but it’s not complete: how do you know that every $T'$-nbhd of $x$ contains the $T$-closure of a $T'$-nbhd of $x$? I only just got up and haven’t really thought much about it yet, but it doesn’t seem to be instantly obvious, though it may well be true.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. Yes, I realize now that my argument is incomplete. Though, if we assume that $(X,T)$ is locally compact, then we are done, right?

Comment: @Cauchy: It takes a little argumentation, but yes, I think so. Given a $T$-compact $K$ and a point $x\notin K$, find a finite cover of $K$ by open sets with compact closures that miss $x$; the complement of the union of their closures should then be a $T'$-open nbhd of $x$ whose $T$-closure is contained in $X\setminus $K$.